# I installed npm and it had 7 vulnerabilities that had to be fixed manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         minimist

  Patched in      >=0.2.1 =1.2.3

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > minimist

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179


  High            Denial of Service

  Package         http-proxy

  Patched in      >=1.18.1

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > browser-sync > http-proxy

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         yargs-parser

  Patched in      >=13.1.2 =15.0.1 =18.1.2

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > browser-sync > localtunnel > yargs >
                  yargs-parser

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         yargs-parser

  Patched in      >=13.1.2 =15.0.1 =18.1.2

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > browser-sync > yargs > yargs-parser

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         lodash

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   http-proxy-middleware [dev]

  Path            http-proxy-middleware > lodash

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         lodash

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > browser-sync > easy-extender > lodash

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523


  Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         lodash

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   lite-server [dev]

  Path            lite-server > lodash

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523

found 7 vulnerabilities (6 low, 1 high) in 354 scanned packages
  7 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

---

I tried to manually update the version of each package and patch them but still shows the vulnerabilities.
Please can anyone suggest me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: if vulnerabilities creating any problem then and then you need to fix it otherwise it will work fine. I also faced same problem many time but my app work always proper without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lodash prototype pollution problem was fixed at https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/4759/ . You should wait for the next lodash release. Also, babel is planning to get rid of lodash( https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11726 ).

Another problem that is a dependency of lite-server was already reported at
https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/176. However, lite-server is not maintained right now. Maybe, you can manually edit package-lock.json and resolve it.

Comment: Yesterday, github noticed me that new lodash version was published. Github will create PR to resolve this problem automatically or you can use `npm audit fix`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely certain that you solved all vulnerabilities you'd like to skip the audit, you can do so by appending --no-audit.

`npm install --no-audit`

or npm will fix for you

`npm audit fix`

But this will update version of modules. Which might lead to breaking of code.

Answer (score 1):

IF `npm audit fix` does not solve the issue, it means there's not yet a combination of your dependency graph that has these issues fixed.

This could mean that one of your dependencies has a vulnerable sub-dependency, but they haven't yet upgrade their dependencies.

Best thing you can probably do is open tickets for these packages, like `lite-server`.

It might also be worth finding out what the actual vulnerability is. Often vulnerabilities that I see via `npm audit` end up not really affecting me.